# Checkbox Change event to trigger another field to be required

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a form with several checkbox fields and a corresponding Comments fields for each checkbox. I dynamically create these fields. For example, the checkbox field, *tag1*, would correspond to *comments1*. When the checkbox is checked, I don't want to require comments. When it is not checked, I want to require comments.

Sometimes the fields are pre-populated based on a user's last input. In other words, the checkbox may already be checked when the page loads or it may not be. I have logic set to build the corresponding comments field as *required* or not required based on this.

Everything situation seems to be working except one. When I check the box and then uncheck the box, the form allows me to submit with no comments. Below is what I have tried.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
  var checkbox = $(this),
    otherInput = $('#comments' + this.id.replace('tag', ''));


  otherInput.removeProp('required', !checkbox.is(':checked'));
  if (!checkbox.not(':checked')){
    otherInput.prop('required',true);
  }
});
```

--------------------second attempt

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
  var checkbox = $(this),
    otherInput = $('#comments' + this.id.replace('tag', ''));

  otherInput.prop('required', !checkbox.not(':checked'));
  otherInput.removeProp('required', !checkbox.is(':checked'));

});
```

Both of these solve the same situations, except the one noted above. Please advise.

Comment: What is purpose of `otherInput.removeProp('required', !checkbox.is(':checked'));` at second example?

Comment: @guest271314 when the user checks the checkbox it will remove the required attribute from the corresponding comments field

Comment: Yes, though previous line `otherInput.prop('required', !checkbox.not(':checked'));` achieves this, yes? Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate issue?

Comment: Using [`removeProp`](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) here seems wonky (documentation says, _"Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected."_ - I think you can include `required` in that list, that's native) - try and just use `.prop` to set it to true/false, as @guest271314 already suggested.

Comment: @CBroe what if the user accidentally checks the box, then unchecks the box. How can I ensure that I am requiring comments at the correct time?

Comment: _"what if the user accidentally checks the box, then unchecks the box."_ `change` event handler should be called, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle the 'required' property based on checkbox status

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
  var checkbox = $(this),
    otherInput = $('#comments' + this.id.replace('tag', ''));

  otherInput.prop('required', !checkbox.is(':checked'));

});
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybtbu1qd/)

Comment: Good answer +1  If you can, it's a good idea to provide a demo of the concept, *either using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or by pressing Ctrl+M in the editor and creating a stack snippet example.*

Answer (score 0):

When the "submit" button is pressed, do your validation:

psuedocode:

```
onSubmitPressed: function(){
   if(checkbox is checked){
      // alert user field is required;
      return false;
   }else{
      return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had some bad syntax, however it was not throwing an error. I changed my first attempt to:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
  var checkbox = $(this),
    otherInput = $('#comments' + this.id.replace('tag', ''));

  otherInput.removeProp('required', !checkbox.is(':checked'));

  if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)')){
    otherInput.prop('required',true);
    console.log('working');
  }
});
```

This now adds and removes the required attribute based upon the checkbox being checked or not checked.